# Hibernate GeneratedValue does not works properly

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, db2

Good night, I'm trying to use the increment implementation through Hibernate's IncrementGenerator strategy.

However, in the query it does not add the SCHEMA in SQL:

> select max(nr_prop) from prop_tran

Expected to be:

> select max(nr_prop) from db2ozt.prop_tran

The class is as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROP_TRAN", schema = "DB2OZT")
public class RuralProperty implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "NR_PROP")
  @GenericGenerator(name="id_for_prop", strategy="org.hibernate.id.IncrementGenerator")
  @GeneratedValue(generator="id_for_prop")
  private Short nmrProp;

  ...
}
```

Version: **5.4.32.Final**

Obs. *I can't add sequence or auto increment in the database. There are development restrictions.*

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the schema to use for the sequence as parameter to the `@GenericGenerator`:

```
@GenericGenerator(
  name = "id_for_prop",
  strategy = "org.hibernate.id.IncrementGenerator",
  parameters = {
    @Parameter(name = "schema", value = "DB2OZT")
  }
)
```